# How to add a newline between sequences with Pyyaml?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, yaml, pyyaml

I've searched and I haven't found very much information on this. I'm writing a Python script to take a list of dictionaries and dump it to a yaml file. For example, I have code like the following:

```
import yaml

dict_1 = {'name'  : 'name1',
          'value' : 12,
          'list'  : [1, 2, 3],
          'type'  : 'doc'
}

dict_2 = {'name'  : 'name2',
          'value' : 100,
          'list'  : [1, 2, 3],
          'type'  : 'cpp'
}

file_info = [dict_1, dict_2]

with open('test_file.yaml', 'w+') as f:
    yaml.dump(file_info, f)
```

The output that I get is:

```
- list:
  - 1
  - 2
  - 3
  name: name1
  type: doc
  value: 12
- list:
  - 1
  - 2
  - 3
  name: name2
  type: cpp
  value: 100
```

When what I really want is something like this:

```
- list:
  - 1
  - 2
  - 3
  name: name1
  type: doc
  value: 12
                  ## Notice the line break here
- list:
  - 1
  - 2
  - 3
  name: name2
  type: cpp
  value: 100
```

I've tried putting `\n` and the end of the dictionaries, using `file_info.append('\n')` between the dictionaries, using `None` as a final key in the dictionary, but nothing has worked so far. Any help is greatly appreciated!

I'm using Pyyaml 5.4.1 with Python 3.9.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can dump each object one at a time following each with a new line.

```py
with open('test_file.yaml', 'w+') as f:
    for yaml_obj in file_info:
        f.write(yaml.dump([yaml_obj]))
        f.write("\n")
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that did it! I can't upvote since I dont have 15 rep but I accepted!